# My network icon is always a question mark but I have acces to internet

Tags: networking, network-manager

My network icon is always a question mark in both wired and wireless connection
but everything network related works correctly.

[image: icon is a question mark like you can see in screen shot]

Comment: hey man this worked for me, hope it does for you too. [Question mark icon instead of wifi icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029361/question-mark-icon-instead-of-wifi-icon)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [Disable Network Connectivity Checking in Ubuntu:](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/disable-network-connectivity-checking-ubuntu-17-10)
- Open Settings
- Select Privacy
- Turn ‘network connectivity checking’ off

Comment: Icon problem solved but connection issue remains. Example: Twitter is not working but fast.com is working.

Answer (score 6):

I had same issue. Googled for answer and found that if you edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and insert the line

```
dns=default
```

to the `[main]` section and the question mark over the lan icon disappears.

Comment: Insert the line in which section?

Comment: Adding the line to the [main] section worked for me.

Comment: I followed this instruction and it seemed to fix it, but after a reboot, _all_ internet connectivity was gone until I reverted this and rebooted again.