# Why is there a question mark on the LAN icon in Gnome panel?

Tags: gnome, 18.04

I have a very normal ethernet adapter. After upgrading to 17.10, and therefore now using Gnome instead of unity, the network has a question mark on a grey network icon. Why’s that?

[image: Question mark on network symbol]

Comment: It could be a theme thing. Meaning, the usual icon cannot be found, and instead, a question mark icon is displayed. Try switching to another icon theme.

Comment: I’m using the standard Ubuntu theme and wouldn’t even know how to change the icon theme on the Gnome panel.

Comment: Is that question mark not going away after sometime or after you soft restart or logout and log on??

Comment: No, it’s not going away as long as I am connected to wired LAN. https://askubuntu.com/questions/990225/my-network-icon-is-always-a-question-mark-but-i-have-acces-to-internet seems to be (almost) the same, only that I have no question mark when on wi-fi.

Comment: Before changing the theme.. Try to access networks via settings and give any name to the existing LAN Connection.

Comment: I'm using Gnome now. I think I see the question mark when I am connected to the LAN but not to the Internet. Could this be the case?

Comment: @MPi can you go through these pics https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR70e.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdDRR.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nj2Ml.png and try to off the connection once and on again. when i swtich on my desktop pc, for some minutes it will show that ? mark and then it becomes normal as you see in the pic.

Comment: @MPi please ignore my comments, i was referring to 18.04 where as your question related to 17.10. Thank You.

Comment: I see in your pictures that your wired connection has a rate label next to it (1000 MB/s). I do not have that. Perhaps the system is trying to figure out the speed and fails, thus setting the question mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

[Question mark icon instead of wifi icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029361/question-mark-icon-instead-of-wifi-icon)

> Settings > Privacy > Connectivity Checking
>
> Set it OFF. (Then, restart your WiFi connection, thanks to @Dante's
>   comment below).

Comment: Well, it’s not WiFi in my case (look closely at the icon), but the same applies for wired connections. I would never have found this – it seems like quite a useless feature to me if it does not explain itself.

Comment: I was in the same spot: wired connection... but it solved my problem

Comment: +1 had issue with wired connection and turning off the 'Connectivity Checking' --> turning off 'Wired' --> enabling 'Wired' helped.