# WiFi signal icon changed to question mark after changing DNS address

Tags: 20.04, network-manager, dns

I used the graphical network manager to change my DNS server to the OpenDNS address.

[image]

Everything works fine but the WiFi signal icon has changed to question mark.

[image]

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1029415/1120661) works, but I want to find and fix the problem instead of disabling a feature.

I also tried [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457875/393910) but no luck.

---

### Update:

Result of `curl -v http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/` with OpenDNS address:

```
$ curl -v http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/
*   Trying 35.224.99.156:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to connectivity-check.ubuntu.com (35.224.99.156) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: connectivity-check.ubuntu.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

---

### Update 2:

result of `curl -v http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/` with my ISP's DNS address:

```
$ curl -v http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/
*   Trying 78.46.14.94:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to connectivity-check.ubuntu.com (78.46.14.94) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: connectivity-check.ubuntu.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Date: Fri, 28 Aug 2020 10:07:04 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< X-NetworkManager-Status: online
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host connectivity-check.ubuntu.com left intact
```

So my local DNS says `connectivity-check.ubuntu.com` is `78.46.14.94`, but the OpenDNS says it's `35.224.99.156` and that server is either blocked from Ubuntu for Iran or is censored by the government.

Adding the following line to the `/etc/hosts` solved the problem.

```
78.46.14.94     connectivity-check.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: While the wifi status is showing a question mark, can you run `curl -v http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/` and post the output?

Comment: @Brian Turek - Question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your updated info, this is somehow not a problem with NetworkManager or DNS but rather a problem with your connection.  The connection check works by doing a periodic HTTP GET to http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/ and, I think, it expects to see a HTTP 204.  Your computer has connectivity problems to that host (thus the `Recv failure`) which causes NetworkManger to go into the question mark state.  For comparison, here's my curl output:

```
$ curl -v http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com
*   Trying 35.224.99.156:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to connectivity-check.ubuntu.com (35.224.99.156) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: connectivity-check.ubuntu.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Date: Fri, 28 Aug 2020 09:46:36 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< X-NetworkManager-Status: online
<
* Connection #0 to host connectivity-check.ubuntu.com left intact
```

I even set my /etc/hosts to resolve connectivity-check.ubuntu.com to the same IP as you to avoid DNS differences.

Is it possible you have something on your network that is blocking plaintext HTTP connections or something?

Comment: I am from Iran. Half the internet is either blocked by sanctions or censored by the regime! I found the problem with your help, thanks.