# Wifi sign question mark

Tags: wireless

I have Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. Wi-Fi is connect but I have no internet connection. There’s a question mark on top of the wifi sign on the desktop. When I go to wifi settings, wifi is on but still no internet.

I tried the following possible solutions with the following results

`ping -c4 www.google.com` Result: ...
I disabled automatic DNS and set it to `IP 8.8.8.8` Result: ...

Comment: The question mark usually indicates a DNS issue. Please check your configuration to see, if you have valid DNS servers configured.

Comment: @BulletBob I run command nmcli device show <device> | grep IP4.DNS and I’ve got this 192.168.0.254

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question mark icon instead of wifi icon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029361/question-mark-icon-instead-of-wifi-icon)

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Went to privacy settings and turned of network verification

Answer (score 0):

The following user seemed to have a similar problem in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029361/question-mark-icon-instead-of-wifi-icon). There are several possible solutions mentioned in this thread

- Do you have a vpn running? If yes try to disable it and run
  `sudo service network-manager restart`
- Do the following to see if it might be a problem with name resolution / DNS: `ping -c4 www.google.com` and `ping -c4 8.8.8.8` If only the second one works, then its probably due to a DNS problem. Then try to disable automatic DNS and set 8.8.8.8 for google DNS or one of [the following for privacy aware DNS](https://securitytrails.com/blog/dns-servers-privacy-security)

edit1: For future posts try to include much more informations about your system, your problem, the solutions you tried, but didn't work. It doesn't have to be techy, but additional informations maybe even seemingly trivial ones help others to spot the possible root of the problem.

edit2: an other [reddit-thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/co1nfd/the_question_of_question_mark_which_is_in_the/) with a similar problem. User Galgaleshs answer:

> That icon means that your system cannot correctly contact either your distro's website or the gnome website, depending on which distro
> you use. It means "there is some connectivity to the internet but we
> can't assure everything will work correctly".
>
> This might be because a firewall is blocking it, because your network
> uses a "captive portal" which requires cookies, or you use a weird VPN
> that doesn't support the gnome network manager or something else.
> Before anyone can diagnose this issue, what is your os , version, the
> country you're in and how are you connected to the internet? Is it a
> home line, hotel, workplace,..?