# Why does Network Manager status show a question mark “?”?

Tags: networking, network-manager

Question Mark `?` in the status of Network Manager of Ubuntu Linux even though Network Get Connected.

Why does a question mark `?` Appear in the status of Ubuntu Network Manager?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My network icon is always a question mark but I have acces to internet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990225/my-network-icon-is-always-a-question-mark-but-i-have-acces-to-internet)

Answer (score 2):

This status of Question Mark “?” Sign or a “?” indicator in the Network Manager Applet despite the network status connected “is not an error in Network Manager” you need to change the settings of connectivity checking to OFF

How to get rid of that “?” Status in the nm-applet is goto

Goto to -------- Settings/Privacy/Connectivity Checking – and Switch it off.

[image]